# React Native PermissionsAndroid always returns "never_ask_again" for location on Android

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, geolocation, location

really stuck here and need help.

PermissionsAndroid always returns "never_ask_again" and react-native-permissions always returns "restricted"
Below is the code snippet:

```
async _getLocationAsync(){
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

    Permissions.request('location').then(response => {
      // Returns once the user has chosen to 'allow' or to 'not allow' access
      // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
      Alert.alert(" ",response);
    });
} else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    //this.nextAction();
    Alert.alert(" ",Platform.OS);
}}


AndroidManifest.xml

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
```

compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

minSdkVersion 16

targetSdkVersion 25

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

---

Below code is with PermissionsAndroid, gives me "never_ask_again" response.

```
async _getLocationAsync(){
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    var permissions = [
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    ];

    try {
        PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(permissions).then(granted => {
             Object.entries(granted).map(([key, value]) => {
                 Alert.alert(key,value);
             });
            //Alert.alert(granted);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert(granted);
    }
} else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    //this.nextAction();
    Alert.alert(Platform.OS);
}
}
```

I have tried on 2 real devices and 2 emulators already and its the same output.

I also tried with targetSDKVersion=23 and buildSDKVersion=23 and its the same output.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.4

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is what i found so far:
- react-native-facebook-login & PermissionsAndroid dont work together
- react-native-geolocation-service + PermissionsAndroid work toegther but breaks the react-native-facebook-login

I think its something to do with play services!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Yay!
If you are ever stuck with the same problem, below can solve the problem:

Scenario: You are using: 
react-native-facebook-login 
react-native-geolocation-service 
(I think the same issue also occurs if you use PermissionsAndroid. )

The two clash with each other. geolocation works but facebook login crashes the app.

Below are the settings that worked for me:

```
build.gradle

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}

compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
compile(project(':react-native-geolocation-service')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+") { 
    force = true;
}
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+") {
    force = true;
```

inside build.gradle of react-native-facebook-login module (found in node_modules folder), change the facebook-android-sdk to 4.19.+, as below

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.+')
```

PS: Havent tested in multiple android devices yet.

Also, this page is helpful for similar issues:
https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/229